# Find the double quotes values and print them using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file with 1000 rows in it

For example:

```
chr1        Cufflinks        transcript        34611        36081        1000        -        .        gene_id "FAM138A"; transcript_id "uc001aak.3"; FPKM "1.2028600217"; frac "1.000000"; conf_lo "0.735264"; conf_hi "1.670456"; cov "0.978610";
```

I want to search file and extract the values after string `FPKM`, like

```
"1.2028600217"
```

Can I do it using `awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't care which column does the `FPKM` show in, you could:

```
grep -Po '(?<=FPKM )"[^"]*"' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk, but this is a simple substitution on a single line so sed is better suited:

```
$ cat file
chr1 Cufflinks transcript 34611 36081 1000 - . gene_id "FAM138A"; transcript_id "uc001aak.3"; FPKM "1.2028600217"; frac "1.000000"; conf_lo "0.735264"; conf_hi "1.670456"; cov "0.978610";
$ sed 's/.*FPKM *"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' file
1.2028600217
```

Comment: it is giving me the entire columns not the FPKM value

Comment: Then you copy/pasted the script incorrectly or there is something about yoru input file that you haven't shared with us.